# awk and bash var / command interaction

Tags: bash, csv, awk, ls

I'd like to get the simplest way of creating a csv file with a bash script that receives two parameters: $var1 it's the folder to list, $var2 a simple alfanumeric string pattern to match.

Current version select the correct files and write a fine csv file, but i'd like to add a path to each file name (path is stored in var1) and also write an "executable" Yes/Now field using the ls -F label option.

```
  ls -lF "$var1"/*"$var2"* | awk {'print $9";$5";"$2";"$1'}
```

Using `var1='.'; var2='sh'` I get

```
./2.sh*;1283;1;-rwxr--r--
./2.sh~*;1285;1;-rwxr--r--
./3.sh*;913;1;-rwxr--r--
./3.sh~*;849;1;-rwxr--r--
./4.sh*;411;1;-rwxr--r--
./4.sh~*;411;1;-rwxr--r--
./5.sh*;413;1;-rwxr--r--
./5.sh~*;386;1;-rwxr--r--
```

which is similar  to what I need. 
If i am in the bash directory I want this output

```
bash/2.sh;1283;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/2.sh~;1285;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/3.sh;913;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/3.sh~;849;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/4.sh;411;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/4.sh~;411;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/5.sh;413;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
bash/5.sh~;386;1;-rwxr--r--;Yes
```

Comment: Edit your question to show some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Also look at the `stat` command for displaying information about files.

Comment: I found that using `var1=bash` I get an error saying the bash/*sh* can't be accessed. it reads * as a character and not as a wildcard for some reason.
I'll check stat command too, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used sed to substitute ls output, adding a yes field where the -F appended '*' was. Thus I got to print that field easily with awk. I generated and stored relative path into a _dir variable and used simple quotes to include it into awk print.

`sed 's/\*$/\ Yes/'`   `awk {'print "'$_dir/'"$9";"$5";"$2";"$1";"$10'}`

Still not the "simplest way". But I'm getting there.
I'll try stats, which seems quite useful.

I got an error when trying to pass pattern as an argument to a function using recursion, but thats the topic for a differente question.